# How to change the order of layers added to the map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, basemap

I have two feature collections(a border of a country and point locations of surveys conducted) and 30 images. I would like the feature collections to be displayed on top of all 30 images but I can only seem to get them to display as the bottom layer under the 30 images. Here is a link to my code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/36a216f0598b2c397ad566f94cd23269

```
Map.centerObject(Benin_pt,6);


///Dates that need to be classified 11/01/12-02/01/18

//Filtering to date

 var AquaFilt=Aqua.filterDate('2013-02-01','2013-02-28');
 print(AquaFilt);

 function addtoMap(image){
 var id=image.id
 print(id);
 image=ee.Image(image.id).select('sur_refl_b01','sur_refl_b04','sur_refl_b03')
 var date=image.get('system:time_start')
 date=ee.Date(date)
 Map.addLayer(image,Aqua_vis,'Aqua'+date)

 }


 AquaFilt.evaluate(function(AquaFilt){
 AquaFilt.features.map(addtoMap)
 });


Map.addLayer(DHS_PSU, {'color':'FF0000'}, 'DHS_PSU');
var Benin= Africa.filterMetadata('COUNTRY','equals','Benin');
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(0).mask(0).paint(Benin,0,2),{},'Benin');
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I've found that the layer defined last within the code will be at the top of the list of layers within the map view.